# Linking to system Eigen failing with undefined references in emmintrin.h

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cluster-computing, linker-errors

I'm having a problem at the link stage of compiling an application that links to several user built libraries.

These libraries link to the system Eigen 3 install, and all libraries were built using the same compiler and flags (gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)) This is on a RHEL 7.3 system (large cluster that uses module system to load/unload compilers).

What's strange is I built many other applications that linked to these same libraries that link to Eigen. All compile and link fine. This one application (not my code, but depends on same libs), is compiling fine but then spewing errors like this:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:114: undefined reference to `_mm_set1_pd'
/nas/longleaf/home/deleeke/dogwood/sfw/ibamr/ibamr-master-scorep/ibtk/lib/libIBTK3d.a(libIBTK3d_a-LEInteractor.o): In function `double __vector Eigen::internal::pset1<double __vector>(Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<double __vector>::type const&)':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/emmintrin.h:64: undefined reference to `_mm_set1_pd'
```

But this function is indeed defined in the `emmintrin.h` file it is pointing to. I know this header has something to do with instruction sets, but that's the extent of my knowledge.

I have not found any resources in my online searches or even going to the sysadmin's who run this cluster I'm working on. They all just groan a little bit and wave their hands around.

I know this code compiles on other machines -- so it has me thinking it has something to do with libgcc?

Can anyone give me some tips on how to trouble shoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a 32bit vs 64bit problem? That some of your library are 32-bit and you are trying to compile a 64-bit application? Or the other way round?

Comment: Eigen is a header only library and the undefined reference is happening in a header provided by gcc. You're right to suspect that something wrong with the compiler installation.